# Android - ImageButton onClick working in ICS and JB but not in GB

Tags: android, onclick, imagebutton, android-2.3-gingerbread

I've created a somewhat simple layout with a total of 4 buttons: 3 buttons at the bottom of the layout are side by side (in a RelativeLayout) and on huge button almost in the middle of the screen.

On Ice Cream Sandwich and Jellybean, I can click any of the buttons and everything works fine (i.e.The respective onClick functions are called) but weirdly enough on Gingerbread any of the 3 buttons at the bottom work but not the one in the middle. onClick fires off many instructions, none of which are being executed so as far as I can tell, it's not being called and I don't know why.

Code for layout is given below. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/main_layout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/main_off"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="10" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button_activate"
        android:layout_width="155dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="170dp"
        android:layout_weight="7.2"
        android:background="@drawable/transparent"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:onClick="activate"
        android:src="@drawable/transparent" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:layout_weight="2" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/button_help"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:background="@drawable/transparent"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
            android:onClick="openhelp"
            android:src="@drawable/transparent" />


        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/button_settings"
            android:layout_width="55dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button_help"
            android:background="@drawable/transparent"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
            android:onClick="opensettings"
            android:src="@drawable/transparent" />


        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/button_contact"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button_help"
            android:background="@drawable/transparent"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
            android:onClick="opencontact"
            android:src="@drawable/transparent" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Activity that calls the layout (main.xml):

```
//bunch of imports

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById (R.id.main_layout);

    boolean serviceOn = isMyServiceRunning();

    if(serviceOn==true) layout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.main_on);
    else if (serviceOn==false) layout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.main_off); 
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById (R.id.main_layout);

    boolean serviceIsOn = isMyServiceRunning();

    if(serviceIsOn==true) layout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.main_on);
    else if (serviceIsOn==false) layout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.main_off);
}



public void activate(View v){
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById (R.id.main_layout);
    Resources res = getResources();

    Drawable on = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.main_on);
    Drawable off = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.main_off);

    if (layout.getBackground().getConstantState() == off.getConstantState()){
        layout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.main_on);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "App has been activated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        turnon();
    }
    else if (layout.getBackground().getConstantState() == on.getConstantState()){
        layout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.main_off);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "App has been deactivated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        turnoff();
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can run this fine on my emulator for both 2.2 and 2.3.

The only thing I can suggest is to try to remove drawables (maybe some settings there are screwing things up), or try to make your relative layout height 0dp, since you are using weight_sum

Comment: Tried your suggestions but no luck so far. I even tried putting the ImageButton inside the RelativeLayout but still no luck. The thing is, when I enable touch sounds, I can hear the button being pushed but nothing happens. Usually this would be an issue with the activity's code but the code works great for JB and ICS...

EDIT: I tried implementing onClick for the button inside the activity instead of just defining it in the XML but that didn't help either.

Comment: Can you edit your original post with your activity that is calling this xml? I really can't seem to recreate your errors on my 2.2 / 2.3 emulators -- have you tried running it on 2.2 or 2.3.3 emulator?

Comment: Yup, tried running on the emulator but still the same problem. I've edited my original post to include the activity that loads the resource (and included the onClick method for the button as well) minus alot of irrelevant code of course. It really doesn't make sense to me. The button is being pushed, the touch sounds confirm that much, but the onClick method along with its many sub-methods is not being called, ONLY on Gingerbread. The issue doesn't really seem to be with the layout but the code works just fine on other versions. =( Thanks for all your help so far!

Comment: My guess is it is hitting the activate method, but the if and else if is both not being hit. Try to log or toast the values you are comparing like so; Toast.makeText(this, "curr constant state: " + layout.getBackground().getConstantState());  .... maybe a few for the on.getconstantstate and off.getconstantstate .... I really think it is a small nuance like this since you say it it works on 4.0.3 but not on 2.3.3, but be some sort of compatibility that is getting broken somewhere. And no problem, thats why we're here on stack :)

Comment: Finally, fixed it! It was the if statement as you said. For some reason getConstantState was returning different state/bitmap/etc values for the 2 drawables, even though they're the same images! (Found using the insanely awesome debugger tool in Eclipse) To solve the issue, I declared the on and off drawables as global variables and used that everywhere (in onCreate etc) instead of using the id from the R file. I guess GB just isn't as smart as the newer versions. Thanks so much! =) Wouldn't have thought to check the if-statement, seemed fine. :P

Comment: Weird that the problem was only in 4.0.3, but it happens in android :) Glad you fixed your problem, best of luck!